# Can't import CSV data into mongoDB with mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I try to import a CSV file into mongoDB with the `mongoimport` utility like so

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongoimport --db vijay --type csv --headerline --file H:\all lab work\mongo\sampledata.csv
```

But the above command results in the following error

> error validating settings only one positional argument is allowed when
>   input is .csv

Comment: Pls answer i have spent hours for this stupid thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to pass the file in quotes due to the space in the path like so

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongoimport --db vijay --type csv --headerline --file "H:\all lab work\mongo\sampledata.csv"
```